# Minimum sleep time to secrete growth hormones

Tags: sleep, muscle-gain, growth

Obviously sleep is the steroids of natural bodybuilding, cause while you sleep you grow your muscle, and it is well known that we need at least 8 hours of sleep a day.

When you sleep your body secretes hormones, but what is the minimum time required for your body to begin secreting hormones while you sleep?

For example If I take a 2 hours nap would my muscle "grow" because of hormones that my body secretes, or do I need more time until growing process begins.

Anyways you need to sleep 8 hours but I have been wondering this a long time ago.

Comment: I think you mean a different word than segregated? Segregation is the act of setting apart.

Comment: @JohnP Lol, I think that too

Answer (score 3):

If I recall the optimal amount of sleep for "standard" athletes is around 7h30 (+/- 30 minutes) going on the higher side if your other recovery factors (food, stress, etc.) are diminished (e.g. you're dieting down and training hard, you're in the middle of a high volume cycle, you live a stressful life, etc.). I'd recommend you read [sleep, part 1](http://www.strengtheory.com/sleep-pt-1/) and [sleep, part 2](http://www.strengtheory.com/poor-recovery-and-increased-muscle-breakdown-insufficient-sleep-part-2/) by coach and world record holder powerlifter Greg Nuckols on the interactions of sleep with strength sports and health.